# Invalid grant while trying to obtain access token from IdentityServer using third party identity providers and authorization code grant

Tags: google-oauth, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to implement authorization and authentication service what support user login using **Google+** identity services and internal **username/password** authentication. As a platform I decide to use **IdentityServer4** and **ASP.NET Core 2.1**. Start point is [IdentityServer and ASP.NET Identity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity).

It works, but for my purpose I want to obtain **access token** using **authorization code** grant. Here is my Resources and Clients:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new IdentityResource[]
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        new IdentityResources.Email(),  
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(IConfiguration config)
{
    return new Client[]
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientName = "MVC Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

            RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"},
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc"},

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
            },

            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
        },
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "test_client_auth_code",
            ClientName = "Test Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

            RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5002"},

            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
            },

            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
        },
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "test_client_implicit",
            ClientName = "Test Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

            RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5002"},

            AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                "api1"
            },

            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
        }
    };
}
```

And I configured **IdentityServer** like this

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityServerConfiguration.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerConfiguration.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerConfiguration.GetClients(Configuration))
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();  

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

        options.ClientId = "688724879532-n7ihk29i1brc9guma71ti890m799fia0.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        options.ClientSecret = "RJWt0BYEbbzJKaUIbMKrypOU";
    });
```

Everything else is the same.

Running MVC client for test was successful and gave me an opportunity to use all possible authentications (Google+ and username/password).

But now, I want to get access token and use it in testing API client through **Postman**. For this case I'm trying to retrieve access token in Postman like this:

[image]

It works fine until I try to login using Google (putting username and password works). In this case I recieve invalid grant error:

```
POST
http://localhost:5000/connect/token
09:50:12.896
Pretty
Raw
POST /connect/token
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.3.0
accept: */*
host: localhost:5000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 222
grant_type=authorization_codecode=4/ZgBr3c7WuDyG92-wYbibVo5wKd0HWXFUkOGrEkZTMmG7KGM9akRrMt8sqvWDu9D7HkJxExv6n8HjGfJdbpXlWLcredirect_uri=http://localhost:5002client_id=test_client_auth_codeclient_secret=secret
HTTP/1.1 400
status: 400
date: Wed, 26 Sep 2018 19:50:12 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
server: Kestrel
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
pragma: no-cache
transfer-encoding: chunked
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
```

And on my log from IdentityServer I see [this](https://pastebin.com/fhMWTk3M)

On the other hand, when I try to obtain access token using **implicit** grant type authentication using google works.

I read about grant types in IdentityServer4 and as I understand, difference between **authorization code** and **implicit** grant type are only in resulted access token content. Anyway, the problem here doesn't seems to me like a problem of support third party authentication provider. But maybe I misunderstand something.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: remove options.SignInScheme  in the google login

Comment: This didn't help. I still get `(IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultAuthorizationCodeStore) "authorization_code" grant with value: "4/aQAkIzwyt6PsjqzTEfntfDyXnzRRe9DHR3yaldSVcZoaXIPwp_Sr
7ikcn-vHIVb7SwKhG1Qdq2UuAWygEbuJNUU" not found in store.` and `(IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator) Invalid authorization code: ["4/aQAkIzwyt6PsjqzTEfntfDyXnzRRe9DHR3yaldSVcZoaXIPwp_Sr7ikcn-vHIVb7Sw
KhG1Qdq2UuAWygEbuJNUU"],`

Comment: What type of client did you make in Google developers console

Comment: Where can I get this information? I used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x for configuration and IdentityServer4 documentation.
The problem is that I can authenticate in Google+ using `implicit` grant  and get errors using `authorization code` grant.

Comment: Same issue to you :'(